# how to Change font size, Without changing the size of button in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

In the following code I want to change just inner font size not the button size.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .sm {
                font-size:x-small;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="sm">submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to specify height

Comment: Reduce the button padding by 1/2 the pixel value that you increase the text by if you want it to remain centered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the text size without changing the button size, you would need to fix the size of the button. This can be done using `height` and `width` in CSS. That way you can change the `font-size` without having it affect the button size.

Take a look at my code below. As you can see, with the `height` and `width` changed, the button is now a fixed size. This is proven by the text being larger than the button.

CSS

```
button {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button>
Hello
</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use span tag which worked quite well for me.

```
 <button><span style="font-size:10px;">ClickMe</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your style to this

```
.sm
{
  font-size:20px;
  height:30px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Another method to achieve this would be to take advantage of the 3rd dimension.

This method does not require you to fix the size of your button and allows it to still adapt to the content size. It would also scale any svg or other content you put in the button to provide a nice hover pop effect.

HTML

```
<button>
    <div>
        Button Text
    </div>
</button>
```

CSS

```
button div {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.14s ease;
}

button:hover div {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) scale(1.05);
}
button:active div {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) scale(1.08);
}
```

I am not sure this is what your trying to achieve but I think its a neat solution and I thought I'd share it in case anyone else want to try it.